# Should a merged question be closed?

Tags: discussion, moderation, close-reasons

I merged a duplicate question, but the question that was merged still "counts" as unanswered. Should the question be closed?

[Bulk check-in of files to library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/bulk-check-in-of-files-to-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say close it, in fact delete it - in this case there isn't even anything to merge.

It begs the question: "what does merge mean in this context?".

Comment: +1 Definitely close as dupe. Merge is used when there are answers in both places (moved to one question only).

Comment: Ok closed. I usually dont delete unless Q is offensive/spam